# Scrapy "too many open files" error, caused by too many sockets

Tags: python, scrapy

I've met a problem that gets `error 24: too many open files.`
After searching I've changed ulimit to 102400...

However my spider still get this error after running for 1 week.

At first I thought it was caused by my pipeline(I changed this), so I checked the `/proc/{pid}/fd` and found so many socket opened.

BTW, you can find code here: https://github.com/yz21606948/sinaSpider/tree/master/sina

Comment: put in question full Traceback. There are other usefull informations.

Comment: do you run it all the time without stoping script ? It may open new connection to Mongo for every item. See example [Write items to MongoDB](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb) - it closes client.

Comment: @furas Thank you~ Actually I changed pipeline from MongoDB to a single file. Also, I've checked fd and I can make sure that this file is only opened once.  I have no idea whether this error is caused by connect fail to proxy or something else...

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by increasing the limit using

```
ulimit -n unlimited
```